# How to stop unwrapping nil values from Parse Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, casting

I'm having trouble getting my information back from a saved array in Parse. I'm saving the information like this.....

```
videoARY = [videoId, vidTitleText, vidDescription, vidIMG]
        let videoSave = PFObject(className:"UserVideos")
        videoSave["userObjectId"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId
        videoSave["vid\(saveValueLBL.text!)user"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
        videoSave["vid\(saveValueLBL.text!)"] = videoARY
        videoSave.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error ) -> Void in
            if success == true
            {
                print("Success")
            }
        }
```

In a different viewcontroller I'm initializing an array like this....

```
var vid1array = [String]!()
```

and retrieving this way.......

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "UserVideos")
query.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (vid:Array?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if !(error != nil)
    {
        for items in vid!
        {

            if let myfav1 = items["vid1"] as? NSArray
            {
                self.videoDescription1 = myfav1[2] as! String
                self.videoTitle1 = myfav1[1] as! String
                self.videoIMG1 = myfav1[3] as! String
                print(self.videoDescription1)
                print(self.videoIMG1)
                print(self.videoTitle1)

                self.vid1array.append(self.videoTitle1)
                print(self.videoTitle1)

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm printing a successful save and each element of the saved array.  When I try to add one of those elements to vid1array the app crashes I get "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  Please help.

*** UPDATE ***

When I print vid! I get this...

```
vid1 =     (
        "YiiqHq_kNnU",
        "INFINITE \"Back\" Official MV",
        "If you like this video, plz click \"LIKE\" and \"SUBSCRIBE\". INFINITE \"Back\" Official MV INFINITE Official Website : http://www.ifnt7.com INFINITE Official YouTube ...",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YiiqHq_kNnU/default.jpg"
    );
```

It's not nil but I don't see array brackets either, could that be it? I'm printing out the elements I just want to save them to my array so I can use them in my tableview later and the array is coming up nil.

***  FOLLOW UP QUESTION ***

Would it be advised to place this in viewWillAppear vs. I currently have it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: You need to find out which object is nil when the error happens. A guess is `vid`

Comment: I'm getting info back for vid.  Please see update. How can I successfully save these to my array?

Comment: There is no need to save the user object id and user name; simply set the `user` column to be of pointer type and you can just assign `PFUser.CurrentUser()`

Comment: Try using guards ti avoid app crashing. Guard let myVid = vid1 as array? Else { return} then if the cast is successful you can use myVid as a array without forcing unwrapping again